# Android - Camera App passed null surface

Tags: android, service, camera, surfaceview

I have tried every possible solutions given on stackoverflow and still haven't reach what I want. I want to take a picture with the Camera API with a service. The picture should be taken when user light the screen, but the screen is still lock. I saw different post about dummy surface etc... but none of them worked, of course I must have made misatke in my code as I am new with the camera API. My application proceed as so : I schedule an AlarmManager to start a service :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId) {
        Log.i("service","start");
        Calendar finServ=Calendar.getInstance();
        String all=intent.getStringExtra("all");
        nomevt=all.split(Pattern.quote("**"))[3];
        Scanner sc;
        String str="";
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File(getFilesDir(),"Event.evt"));
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                str=sc.next();
                if(all.equals(str)) break;
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!all.equals(str)) stopSelf();
        else {
            finServ.setTimeInMillis(toMillis(str.split(Pattern.quote("**"))[1]));
            Calendar now=Calendar.getInstance();
            now.setTime(new Date());
            while(finServ.after(now)) {
                PowerManager pm=(PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                if(pm.isScreenOn()) {
                    //AsyncCapture ac=new AsyncCapture(this);
                    //ac.execute("nomevt");
                    photo();
                    Log.i("screen","on");
                    while(pm.isScreenOn()) {
                        pm=(PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    }
                }
                now.setTime(new Date());
            }
            stopSelf();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }`
<br>The service will call `photo()` when the screen is light on. <br> 
`public void photo() {
        cam=Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        try {
            cam.unlock();
            /*WindowManager wm=(WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);*/
            SurfaceView sv=new SurfaceView(this);
            //wm.addView(sv, params);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams param=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(1,1);
            sv.setLayoutParams(param);
            sv.setZOrderOnTop(true);
            SurfaceHolder mHolder=sv.getHolder();
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            Log.i("holder",(mHolder==null)+"");
            cam.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            cam.startPreview();
            cam.takePicture(null,null,this);
            //wm.removeView(sv);
            Log.i("take","picture");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(RuntimeException re) {
            Log.e("error",re.getMessage()+"");
            re.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
        }
    }
```

And in `takePicture()` I simply save the image, this method works as I tested it in an activity.
Logs show the error `Camera : app passed NULL surface`, `error : setPreviewTextureFailed`. I put a log to see if `mHolder` is null but it's not.
Why does `setPreviewDisplay()` throw an error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `SurfaceTexture` and `setPreviewTexture()` instead of `SurfaceHolder`:

```
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
cam.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
```

The error `Camera : app passed NULL surface` has been thrown in `setPreviewDisplay()` is because there was no surface created.

If you still want to use `SurfaceHolder`, you should implement `SurfaceHolder.Callback` first and `setPreviewDisplay()` in `surfaceCreated()` method to make sure a surface was created before you `setPreviewDisplay()`.

Note that the surface will not be created until you add it to the View hierarchy.

**EDIT**

Come back to your error when you `setPreviewTexture()`, because you used `cam.unlock();`, your camera is *temporarily released for another process to use* (read more about `unlock()` method [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#unlock())). That's why you got error `java.io.IOException: setPreviewTexture failed` when you call `setPreviewTexture()`.

The solution is just remove line `cam.unlock();` in your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this multiple times 
It throws an error `setPreviewTexture failed` By "adding the surface to the view hierarchy" you mean add it in my .xml app file ? But how could I access it from the service as the app isn't launch?

Comment: @Biratus No, you can add it at runtime by using `addView()` (you already tried it). As I can see, you are trying to capture image from camera _"without preview"_, right? In that case, I think using texture is the best way for us. Can you please tell me what you got when using `SurfaceTexture`? It perfectly worked for me.

Comment: Yes that's what I want, or use a dummy preview... I already tested SurfaceTexture ! I wrote `cam.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));` then startPreview, takePicture... And it throws `Java.io.IOException: setPreviewTexture failed` when calling `setPreviewTexture`, obviously. And I can't add a surfaceTexture to the view as it's not a view.

Comment: @Biratus Check out my updated answer. I think your problem will be solved.
You don't need a view to use camera. That's why I choose `SurfaceTexture`.

Comment: @Biratus Can you pls tell me if your problem was solved. If not, what kind of error you got?